# Temples in Dvapara yuga

Tags: temple, yuga, dvapara

Are there any references that temple's were constructed during the period? If so share examples, if not why they were emphasized more in Kaliyuga?

Answer (score 2):

The [Devi Bhagavatam](https://www.astrojyoti.com/devibhagavatam28.htm) mentions about the existence of temples even in Satya Yuga.

> Janamejaya said :-- “O Bhagavân! Describe particularly the details of
> the Yuga Dharma. I am now very desirous to hear which Dharma is for
> which Yuga?” 32-54. Vyâsa said :-- O King! I will now show to you by
> example the influence of the religion peculiar to each Yuga; hear it
> attentively. O King! The hearts even of saints are quite disturbed by
> the Yuga Dharma. See! Your father was a religious and high-souled
> monarch; still the wicked Kâlî defiled his mind and prompted him to do
> an act very insulting to a Brâhmana. Otherwise why would he, being a
> renowned prince amongst the Ksattriyas and a descendant of Yayâti,
> thus go and encircle a snake round the throat of an ascetic Brâhmin?
> Therefore, O King! All actions are being influenced by the Yuga
> Dharma. The Pundits, also recognise this. If you try your best to
> perform any religious act, even then the Yuga Dharma would prevail,
> yet you would be able to perform to a certain extent, a part of your
> intention. O King! In the Satya Yuga, the Brâhmins were versed in the
> Vedas, always devoted to worship the Highest Force, with an ardent
> desire to see the Devî; they were devoted to Gâyatrî with Pranava,
> devoted to the meditation of Gâyatrî, always reciting silently
> Gâyatrî, and the Mâyâvîja Mantram, the chief mantram. **In every
> village, the Brâhmins were very eager to erect temples of the Devî
> Mahâ Mâyâ Ambikâ and were truthful, merciful and pure and devoted to
> their own respective works.** The Ksattriyas, skilled in the science of
> the highest knowledge, were ever engaged in doing things ordained by
> the Vedas and were always intent in protecting well their subjects.
> The Vais’yas did their cultivation and trade and the S’ûdras always
> served the other three castes